# Замена по регулярному выражению с использованием массивов (аналог str_replace / preg_replace в PHP)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Вопрос простой, как можно в js по аналогии с php используя два массива

```
var mouss = ['января','февраля','марта','апреля','мая','июня','июля','августа','сентября','октября','ноября','декабря'];
var moui = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'];
```

произвести замену например в строке

```
 var s = "22 декабря";
```

делаю по аналогии так как делал это в php

```
 var str = s.replace(mouss, moui);
```

но ничего не заменяет, как это реализовать правильно??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Аналог `str_replace`:

```js
String.prototype.str_replace = function(find, replace) {
  var regex; 
  var str = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
    regex = new RegExp(find[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "g");
    str = str.replace(regex, replace[i]);
  }
  return str;
};

var mouss = ['января','февраля','марта','апреля','мая','июня','июля','августа','сентября','октября','ноября','декабря'];
var moui = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'];
var s = "22 декабря";
console.log(s.str_replace(mouss, moui));
```

В функцию `str_replace` передаётся два параметра, массивы со строками, которые необходимо найти (`find`) и которыми надо заменить (`replace`).

С помощью `new RegExp(find[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "g")` задаётся регулярное выражение, которое найдёт все вхождения (благодаря `"g"`) подстрок, соответствующих шаблону. `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` экранирует все специальные знаки.

Чтобы добавить регистронезависимость, замените  `"g"` на `"gi"`.

## Аналог `preg_replace`

Если нужен аналог `preg_replace` (т.е. если `find` содержит готовые регулярные выражения), удалите `regex` и используйте `str = str.replace(find[i], replace[i]);`:

```js
String.prototype.preg_replace = function(find, replace) {
  var str = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(find[i], replace[i]);
  }
  return str;
};

var mouss = [/\d+/g, /[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+/g];
var moui = ['<XXX>','<буквы>'];
var s = "22 декабря";
console.log(s.preg_replace(mouss, moui));
```

См. [аналогичное демо на PHP](https://3v4l.org/N6apU).

## Замена односимвольных совпадений

Если нужно заменить одиночные символы на какое-то другое значение, можно использовать ассоциативный массив.

Код на PHP

```
function translit($str) { 
    $rus = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я''); 
    $lat = array('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya'); 
    return str_replace($rus, $lat, $str); 
}
```

можно перевести на JavaScript как

```js
function translit(str) { 
    var chrmap = {
      'А':'A', 'Б':'B', 'В':'V', 'Г':'G', 'Д':'D', 'Е':'E', 'Ё':'E', 'Ж':'Gh', 'З':'Z', 'И':'I', 'Й':'Y', 'К':'K', 'Л':'L', 'М':'M', 'Н':'N', 'О':'O', 'П':'P', 'Р':'R', 'С':'S', 'Т':'T', 'У':'U', 'Ф':'F', 'Х':'H', 'Ц':'C', 'Ч':'Ch', 'Ш':'Sh', 'Щ':'Sch', 'Ъ':'Y', 'Ы':'Y', 'Ь':'Y', 'Э':'E', 'Ю':'Yu', 'Я':'Ya'}; 
    return str.replace(/[А-ЯЁ]/g, function($0) { return chrmap[$0]; }); 
}
 
console.log(translit("ПЕРЕСТРОЙКА"));
```

где `/[А-ЯЁ]/g` находит все заглавные русские буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```js
let str1 = "this is a string";
let arr1 = ['one', 'word', 'string'];
let arr2 = ['1', 'blalba', 'MEGASTRING'];

console.log(str1);
tmpstr = str1.split(' ');

str1 = tmpstr.map((item) => {
  if(arr1.includes(item)) {
   let index = arr1.indexOf(item);
    item = arr2[index];
    return item;
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(str1.join(' '));
```

Comment: аа нет боюсь это не совсем то что недо - у меня там не прямая замена, а именно по поиску в строке, массивы просто идут как порядок поиска\замены

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Можно пример. Что на что из тех двух массивов должно меняться?

Comment: вот я например делал в php что бы заменить в строке русские буквы на латиницу, вот хотел что бы название месяцев менять по такому же принципу function translit($str) {
 $rus = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я'');
 $lat = array('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya');
 return str_replace($rus, $lat, $str);
}

Comment: Я так понял, что имеется некая строка. Каждое слово это строки ищется в первом массиве, если находится, то заменяется элементом из второго с тем же индексом? Правильно?

Comment: да по сути - если в строке имеется элемент из первого массива, то он заменяется на порядковый аналог из 2го - в php этим всё было просто, а вот в js у меня почему то не срабатывает если по аналогии реализовать